# How can i get all the ip address of access points in the wifi ? Android

Tags: android, wifi

I am not able to get the IP address... Is it the right way to get the IP Address of all the access points by scanning through wifi ?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiDemo.wifi.getScanResults();
        ScanResult bestSignal = null;
        for (ScanResult result : results) {


        }

        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();){
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();


                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();){
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        Toast.makeText(wifiDemo, TAG + "IP " + inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please consider adding text to your question in addition to the title, not just dumping your code here and expecting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi access points do not have IP addresses.

Comment: Ok...That makes sense...I am able to get SSID and BSSID(address)... My application is supposed to connect to a wifi controller with some protocol that i have nt decided yet(will be going for TCP as the hardware supports it)... Could you tell me how i can establish a connection...can i connect with this BSSID ???I If so..how?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` approach to get all interfaces? and then iterate to get IP from each interface.

Comment: hmmm.... I tried this...Can you tell me if there is anything wrong ..I just cant get the network interfaces..